# Apply a (sort of a meta) function to a sequence of types

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, map-function

I have a function:

```
template <typename T> std::string foo();
```

which you could think of as taking a type as an input and producing a string.

I also have either a parameter pack, or a tuple, as is more convenient for you; suppose it's

```
using std::tuple<MyParameters...> my_types;
```

Now, I want to invoke `foo<T>` on each type `T` in the pack, or in the tuple's type definition, in sequence.

I realize I can probably get that using a library such as Boost's MPL or Boost Hana, but I don't want to stick all of that into my code, and was wondering if the principle of doing this could be "captured" in something succinct.

Notes:

- Bonus points if you could provide an answer which works with generic lambda's instead of a templated function.
- Answer must be C++14, not C++17.

Comment: `std::string bar[] = {foo<MyParameters>()...};`?

Comment: @T.C.: Yes, actually very simple. Developed this into an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, for this sort of things you need partial specialization.
So struct/classes, non functions.

So if you can demand the work to a method of a variadic struct `bar`, you can write `foo()` calling a method in `bar` (the `operator()`, by example) as follows

```
template <typename T>
std::string foo ()
 { return bar<T>()(); }
```

The following is a full working (I don't know if "succinct" enough) example; it's C++11, if I'm not wrong.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...>
struct bar;

template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct bar<T0, Ts...>
 {
   std::string operator() ()
    { return "type; " + bar<Ts...>()(); }
 };

template <template <typename ...> class C,
          typename ... Ts1, typename ... Ts2>
struct bar<C<Ts1...>, Ts2...>
 {
   std::string operator() ()
    { return "type container; " + bar<Ts1...>()() + bar<Ts2...>()(); }
 };

template <>
struct bar<>
 { std::string operator() () { return {}; } };

template <typename T>
std::string foo ()
 { return bar<T>()(); }

int main ()
 {
   std::cout << foo<int>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo<std::tuple<int, long, short, std::tuple<long, int>>>()
      << std::endl;
   std::cout << foo<std::complex<double>>() << std::endl;
 }
```

p.s.: isn't clear to me what do you mean with "an answer which works with generic lambda's instead of a templated function".

Can you show an example of use?

Comment: This seems a bit baroque... can you explain the benefit of your solution over @T.C.'s, which I developed into ann answer?

Comment: @einpoklum - first of all, I suppose I've misunderstood your question: I understood that you intention was to call something as `foo<std::tuple<int, long, short, std::tuple<long, int>>>()`; if your intention requirement is only another template (but variadic) function that use `foo()`... yes, your solution (T.C. based) is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

@T.C.'s comment nails it...

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> std::string foo() { 
    return std::to_string(sizeof(T)); 
}

template <typename... Ts>
std::array<std::string, sizeof...(Ts)> multi_foo() {
    return { foo<Ts>()... };
}

int main() {
    auto size_strings = multi_foo<char, short, int, long, long long>();
    for(const auto& s : size_strings) { std::cout << s << ' '; };
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

See also a [live version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b3344b392076dca) - producing the expected output:

```
1 2 4 8 8
```

on an x86_64 machine.